# What is the difference between val b=a (a is an Array) and val b=a.clone()?

Tags: scala, reference

I am reading scaladocs and just wondering difference between direct assignment and .clone method.

```
val a=Array(1,2,3,4,5)
```

case 1:

```
val b=a
```

case 2 :

```
val b=a.clone()
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consider this:

```
scala> val a=Array(1,2,3,4,5)
a: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> val b = a
b: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> val c = a.clone()
c: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> b(0) = 0

scala> c(1) = 1

scala> a
res2: Array[Int] = Array(0, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> b
res3: Array[Int] = Array(0, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> c
res4: Array[Int] = Array(1, 1, 3, 4, 5)
```

As you can see, when you do `val b = a`, then `a` and `b` point to the same object. When the object is changed, the change will be seen by both.

On the other hand, when you clone the array, you produce a new array with the same content. Changing this new array does not change the old one.

Answer (score 5):

I believe case 1 just sets the reference of a to b while case 2 creates an entirely new array that is a copy of a and putting the value in b.

In other words if you in case a edit the a array the b array will also be edited this is not the case in case 2

Answer (score 3):

Here is an answer in code:

```
scala> val a = Array(1,2,3,4,5)
scala> a.hashCode()
res12: Int = 1382155266

scala> val b = a
scala> b.hashCode()
res13: Int = 1382155266

scala> val c = a.clone()
scala> c.hashCode()
res14: Int = 2062756135

scala> a eq b
res15: Boolean = true

scala> a eq c
res16: Boolean = false

scala> b eq c
res17: Boolean = false
```

Answer (score 2):

In case 1, both reference leads to the same object while in the second case, a new object is created and a and b do not reference the same object.